# How to add a column to an existing table then use it in a single PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I have a table being created in a PostgreSQL ( version 9 ) database by a third party product and I need to change that table to add a new column then set the column in question to a standard value.

I have the following in my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION alterscorecolumns()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

ALTER TABLE "hi_scores" ADD "total_score" integer;

UPDATE "hi_scores" SET total_score = score1+score2+score3;

$BODY$
```

However, I'm not allowed to do this because it doesn't know that the `total_score` field exists. I just get the message `ERROR: column "total_score" of relation "hi_scores" does not exist.`

I am guessing there is some execution-plan related reason for this and that maybe I need to tell it to run the `ALTER TABLE` before it tries to perform the update, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it that way. The SQL in the function is parsed when you create the function. At the time of the creation of the function the column is not there, so you get the error message.

You will need to use dynamic SQL to run the UPDATE statement.

Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION alterscorecolumns()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
begin
  execute 'ALTER TABLE hi_scores ADD total_score integer';
  execute 'UPDATE hi_scores SET total_score = score1+score2+score3';
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

(Not tested, so there might be syntax errors in there)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed to know. In the end I split the process into two functions ( I had to create the "UPDATE" one after having performed the "ALTER TABLE" function so the interface would allow me to save it ) and then alter function being committed meant that the field existed for me to perform the update one.

Answer (score 0):

Just add DEFAULT  to your statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "hi_scores" ADD "total_score" integer DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I tried it, but it doesn't change the error message.

Answer (score 0):

@mu already provided: if you want to save this procedure as a function, you have to use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`. But only for the `UPDATE`. The `ALTER TABLE` statement works just fine.

As this is obviously a *one-time operation* (can't add the same column twice), it hardly makes sense to persist a function for the purpose. You could use a `DO` statement instead:

```
DO 
$BODY$
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE hi_scores ADD total_score integer;
   EXECUTE 'UPDATE hi_scores SET total_score = score1+score2+score3';
END;
$BODY$;
```

But then again, keep it simple: just execute two SQL statements. As soon as the `ALTER TABLE` is done, the `UPDATE` will just work normally. Inside a transaction or not - doesn't matter, as long you execute them in order.

```
  ALTER TABLE hi_scores ADD total_score integer;

  UPDATE hi_scores SET total_score = score1+score2+score3;
```

Comment: I agree in general but it is useful to have in a function here because the software I'm working with routinely drops and recreates the table from scratch. This is part of the follow-up for that re-creation, so although it only needs to happen once per table creation, that is a scheduled event.

Comment: @glenatron: Why not schedule the simple SQL commands instead?

Comment: Because I am working through the interface to the same tool and it has a facility to call functions in postgres but not to perform ad-hoc queries.